# how to use same source qualifier in two times in joiner in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

i need to archive below query in informatica mapping with joiner

select student.roll_number,lecture.roll_number,name,DOB
from College
join student student on student.id = college.student_id
join student lecture on lecture.id = college.lecture_id;

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to stop you adding same source as an alias and then defining the join on the source qualifier. Just need to manually link up the second aliased source

Answer (score 0):

Both tables are on same DB, then in SQ you can use same above query and only you need to add all query fields on Source definition and SQ. Make sure you have added all fields and data type for fields are correct. No need of joiner transformation.